# sprintf to convert hexadecimal array to decimal char array only reads first byte

Tags: c, arrays, hex, printf, decimal

I have an array:

```
unsigned char datalog[4];
datalog[0] = 0;
datalog[1] = 0xce;
datalog[2] = 0x50;
datalog[3] = 0xa3;
```

These represent the hex value 0xce50a3. Its decimal value is 13521059.

I need to convert this hex value to a decimal array, preferably using sprintf, so that the final outcome will be:

```
finalarray[0] = '1';
finalarray[1] = '3';
finalarray[2] = '5';
finalarray[3] = '2';
finalarray[4] = '1';
finalarray[5] = '0';
finalarray[6] = '5';
finalarray[7] = '9';
```

I've tried several combinations of sprintf inputs, including concatenating my hex array into unsigned long datalogvalue = 0xce50a3. But sprintf only reads its first byte when it converts.

ex:

```
sprintf(finalarray, "%d", *(unsigned long *)datalog);
```

yields:

```
finalarray[0] = '2';
finalarray[1] = '0';
finalarray[2] = '6';
finalarray[3] = ' ';
.....
```

206 is the decimal representation of 0xce. So it's only converting the first hex byte and not the rest.

Any thoughts on how to convert the entire unsigned long into a decimal array?

Comment: What is `datalogvalue`?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean it is converting the first TWO byes?

Comment: What is the value of `sizeof(unsigned long)` in your environment?

Comment: I get another number, because my computer has a different endian-ness. And I don't understand where the space character in finalarray[3] comes from.

Comment: Too much guessing involved, please make a [mcve].

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask] and post an [MCVE].  What architecture are you compiling to? Big or little endian? How is `finalarray[]` declared?

Comment: datalogvalue was my concatenated unsigned long value where i added the bitshifted values of datalog (datalog[0]<<24, datalog[1]<<16, datalog[2]<<8 and datalog[0]) to get datalogvalue = 0x00ce50a3

Comment: Also yes, it looks as if it is converting the first 2 bytes, 0x00 and 0xce.

Comment: @ZabaZoobeus you should probably roll back the edit someone made to your question that made the assumption that `datalogvalue` was a typo.  And then add that information about it into the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

The outcome of casting a `char*` to `unsigned long*` and dereferencing that pointer depends on the endianness of your system. Unless efficiency of this particular calculation is critical for performance of your program, don't use such tricks. Use simple logic.

```
int res = (datalog[0] << 24) +
          (datalog[1] << 16) +
          (datalog[2] << 8) +
          datalog[3];

sprintf(finalarray, "%d", res);
```

If you are required to use `unsigned long` for your type, make sure to use the right format specifier for `unsigned long` in the call to `sprintf`.

```
unsigned long res = (datalog[0] << 24) +
                    (datalog[1] << 16) +
                    (datalog[2] << 8) +
                    datalog[3];

sprintf(finalarray, "%lu", res);
```

Comment: To expand on your first paragraph, doing so is actually undefined behavior due to breaking strict aliasing and thus should just never be done.  (it is okay to cast `unsigned long*` to `char *` and dereference that, though, as there is an exception for the char-family types being allowed to alias anything.

Comment: `datalog[0] << 24` depends on the size of an `int/unsigned` being 32-bits or more.  The type of `res` does not apply to the shift.  Code likely should be `"%lu"` and not `"%ul"`.

Comment: @chux, thanks for raising the size issue and pointing out the format string error.

Answer (score 1):

As some others have mentioned, attempting to read the bytes of an array in order as a number will be system-dependent as Big Endian and Little Endian systems will give different results.

Furthermore, type-punning through pointer-trickery is undefined behavior as it breaks strict aliasing.  The legal way to type pun to a type other than a char-family array involves using unions to represent the data in more than one fashion.  Due to the above Endian issue, though, you should not do that for this problem and instead do the bit-shifting method as mentioned in R Sahu's answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simply solution that does not depend on endian, `int` sizes  or pointer tricks

Form the value

```
//              LU to use unsigned long math
((datalog[0]*256LU + datalog[1])*256 + datalog[2])*256 + datalog[3]
```

Print it

```
sprintf(finalarray, "%lu", value);
```

---

Altogether

```
sprintf(finalarray, "%lu", 
    ((datalog[0]*256LU + datalog[1])*256 + datalog[2])*256 + datalog[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to endianess, the bytes do not appear in the order you think they do:

[***IDEOne Link***](https://ideone.com/rSo1SU)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
unsigned char datalog[4];
char finalarray[20] = {0};

datalog[0] = 0xa3;
datalog[1] = 0x50;
datalog[2] = 0xce;
datalog[3] = 0x00;

sprintf(finalarray, "%lu", *(unsigned long*)datalog);

printf("Answer: %s\n", finalarray);
return 0;
}
```

***Output***

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4180KB
Answer: 13521059
```

Comment: `*(unsigned long*)datalog` can certainly fail alignment requirements

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, endianness makes things abit troublesome here.
In order to be able to reinterpret your buffer as a 32 bit int you would have to take endianness into consideration when packing.

For example, on my system which is little-endian, datalog would be interpreted as: 2739981824 if converted to a 32 bit unsigned int.

Hence I would have to pack my data according to datalog2 in the example below in order to get the desired 13521059.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {

    uint8_t datalog[4];
    datalog[0] = 0;
    datalog[1] = 0xce;
    datalog[2] = 0x50;
    datalog[3] = 0xa3;

    uint32_t temp = *((uint32_t*) datalog);

    printf("%u\n", temp); // 2739981824


    uint8_t datalog2[4];
    datalog2[0] = 0xa3;
    datalog2[1] = 0x50;
    datalog2[2] = 0xce;
    datalog2[3] = 0;

    uint32_t temp2 = *((uint32_t*) datalog2);

    printf("%u\n", temp2); // 13521059

    return 0;
}
```

There is however another problem with what you are asking.

If I interpret your question correctly, you would like to end up with another array where each of the decimals making up 13521059 in base-10, ends up in its own index.

In order to do this you would have to be able to address log2(10) bits with each index, something that is impossible.

Therefore in order to get an array with the packing that you suggest, you would have to manually convert it.